# onServiceResolved or onResolveFailed never get called after resolveService

Tags: java, android

Recently I'm working on detecting bonjour service on android app. I follow the standard Android NSDManager sample and can successfully find the service which result in getting into the function NsdManager.DiscoveryListener.onServiceFound. Then after called resolveService, nothing happens. Neither onServiceResolved nor onResolveFailed are get called. Can any one give me some advice whether I miss something or anything I can do to find the root cause?

Below are my code:(to make it simple, I just paste some main logic)

```
NsdManager mNsdManager = (NsdManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
mNsdManager.discoverServices("_http._tcp.", NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {
   public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
      mNsdManager.resolveService(service, new NsdManager.ResolveListener({
          public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResolveFailed " + serviceInfo + ", errorCode: " + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            InetAddress host = serviceInfo.getHost();
            int port = serviceInfo.getPort();
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceResolved " + serviceInfo);
        }
      });
   }
});
```

thanks

Comment: After doing some testing, I think the root cause is not on the client side, because this piece of code can resolve most of the bonjour services in the LAN except the one that published by https://github.com/watson/bonjour. Not sure if anyone meet the same problem?